# What's the point of the Sonata homepage breadcrumb service?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, breadcrumbs, sonata

I'm learning the sonata stack and I'm stuck at the default template, where breadcrumb are printed:

```
        {% block sonata_page_breadcrumb %}
            <div class="row">
                {% if sonata_seo_context is not defined %}
                    {% set sonata_seo_context = 'homepage' %}
                {% endif %}
                {{ sonata_block_render_event('breadcrumb', { 'context': sonata_seo_context, 'current_uri': app.request.requestUri }) }}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

From the `HomepageBreadcrumbBlockService` class [and this article](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/master/doc/reference/breadcrumb.html) it seems that breadcrumb are "static" and there is no way to print breadcrumb based on the parent/child relation between pages.

So am I wrong? What's the point of manually define a lot of menu items with hardcoded routes for the pages:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getMenu(array $options)
{

    $menu = $this->getMenu($options);

    $menu->addChild('my_awesome_action');

    return $menu;
}
```